# Jquery renders on Safari but not mobile safari

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

Everything works on computer but when I run this page on my phone this script doesn't work. Is there something I need to put in the code or something?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on ("pagecreate", "#pagegone", function(){
            $("p").on ("tap", function(){
                $("p").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagegone">
     <p>Tap on me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you exactly where the error is, but you may want to try it with the `$().ready()` event as specified here https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Where are your jQuery CSS and JS files located? According to your `<script>` tags, they should be in the same directory as the page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing your `viewport` meta tag. Add this snippet:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the `<head>` section of your HTML above the linked CSS file.

In addition, your `data-role="page"` div is not being closed properly. You should add `</div>` after the paragraph tag to properly close the div.

**Reference:** [jQuery Mobile Page Anatomy](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

**EDIT:**

Not sure if this makes a difference, but you may want to change your doctype tag to match that of the standard `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I'm not sure if it's case sensitive but it can't hurt to fix this as well.